# Python Change Directory with non-ASCII characters

Tags: python

I am using the python command

```
os.chdir(base_dir)
```

to change directories. But the string base_dir contains utf-8 characters outside the ASCII range. The directory listing on windows explorer (Windows 7) shows the directory names, in the non-ASCII characters, corresponding to the path base_dir .

However, when  I execute the above command I get the error

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:/Users/abhishek/Desktop/scripting/dir_struct/\xd0\x98\xd0\xbd\xd1\x84\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0'
```

Can somebody tell me how to successfully navigate the directory in python?

My computer's default language is english.

Answer (score 4):

Use a unicode path instead:

```
os.chdir(base_dir.decode('utf8'))
```

Windows paths are UTF-16 encoded, but Python knows how to handle unicode paths correctly and translates these to the correct filesystem encoding for your platform.